# WebSense scanning my site

Tags: security, websense

Good afternoon,

Recently websense bot (or employee) scanned my website.
Let's start with that my website is dedicated to really small group of ppl, in specific country. And so before that i had regional filter which blocked them. I also heard that they dont really have good opinion (In the past, these policies have been criticized because it can block innocent websites or content protected by free speech). But im not sure if is that enough...

I wanted to rangeban their ips, the problem is i cant find any lists with it...
Am i safe with only regional blockade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try searching ARIN or RIPE, but neither it nor regional blocking cant protect totaly. It can be bypassed by using proxy servers or vpn in your specific country.
If group is really small and your website is really confidential, try SSL client certificate authentication.